Apex Trigger Not Firing - Debug Logs Empty
I'm trying to troubleshoot a trigger on the Account object but the debug logs are not showing any entries. Here's what I've done:

Created a new trigger named "BeforeInsertTrigger" on the Account object with a before insert context.
Inside the trigger, I added a simple debug statement: System.debug('BeforeInsertTrigger Hello World!');

Enabled debug logs for the current user with the appropriate trace flag and debug detail


4.Created a new Account record.

5.Checked the debug logs, but there are no entries.

Expected Behavior:
The debug statement should be logged when a new Account is created.
Actual Behavior:
The debug logs are empty.
Question:
Can anyone advise why the debug logs are not showing the trigger execution, even though the trigger is defined and trace flags are enabled?
Additional Information:
Are there any specific log levels I need to consider for this scenario?
Is there anything else I might be missing in my setup?
*** Edit : For the one who needs , @sfdcfox answers fixed my problem. Thanks

If I had to guess, you created a TraceFlag on the trigger, not the user. TraceFlags on a class or trigger are used to define the levels that will be used for that class or trigger, but without setting a TraceFlag on the user, nothing will be logged at all. Create a new TraceFlag on the user, and you should get debug logs.


Make sure that the debug level is set to Finest for Apex Code to capture detailed logs for triggers.

Open the Developer Console to monitor real-time logs and check if the trigger execution is being captured there.


Check this helpful documentation.

How to Capture Debug Logs for Troubleshooting


One does not need debug log  for apex set to finest for trigger debug. That's relevant for use of the Apex Debugger, not for the OP use case of System.debug(xxx)
